# Can't get all array key and values into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When i tried to see all input values, its always showing last ones.

```
function addInput() {
   $('.addElement').append('<label>Sağlık Etkisi</label><input  id="health" name="health[]" type="text" class="form-control message">');
   $('.addElement').append('<label>Yaşam Tarzı Önerisi</label><input id="lifeStyle" name="lifeStyle[]" type="text" class="form-control message">');
   $('.addElement').append('<label>Öneriler</label><input id="advice" name="advice[]"  type="text" class="form-control message">');

}
```

I'm appending 3 input to my form.

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = [];

    $("input[name='health[]']").each(function(index, item) {
        text['health'] = item.value;
    });

    $("input[name='lifeStyle[]']").each(function(index, item) {
        text["lifeStyle"] = item.value;
    });

    $("input[name='advice[]']").each(function(index, item) {
        text["advice"] = item.value;
    });
```

I did `text[index]['health']`, and this gave me error too.

this code on output, always giving me last 3 input value.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: `text['health'] = item.value;` < that just overwrites the last value. You want an array or a comma seperated list?

Comment: yes  @epascarello,

Comment: @epascarello Thanks to Rory answer it's works now ! Also thanks for your answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're overwriting the values of the `health`, `lifeStyle` and `advice` properties in every iteration, hence on the final values in each loop are accessible.

One solution to fix this would be to build arrays of the input values and assign those to the properties instead:

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var healthVals = $("input[name='health[]']").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
  var lifestyleVals = $("input[name='lifeStyle[]']").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
  var adviceVals = $("input[name='advice[]']").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();

  var text = [];
  text['health'] = healthVals;
  text['lifeStyle'] = lifestyleVals;
  text['advice'] = adviceVals;
});
```

Also note that the fact you're looping over the appended elements implies that there can be multiple copies of them. In which case you should remove the `id` attribute from the HTML you append, as it will result in duplicates which is invalid.

Comment: hello. Thanks for your answer. i'm getting empty value  because of item not defined. i did .map(function(item), isn't that correct? Also thanks for your warning about id.

Comment: Apologies, `item` should have been `this`. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: It is work very well now! Thanks for your big help, also i understand very well.